# Service chain in AWS VPC: IDS -> Firewall -> Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create a service chain with EC2 instances.

Τo be more precise I have 3 ec2 instances 1) an Intrusion Detection System (IDS) 2) a firewall 3) a web server, and I want all the traffic to follow this path ( IDS-> FW-> Sever).. before reaching the server.

Can traffic mirroring feature help? (or it is just for monitoring)

Thank you.

Comment: Some ideas: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/securing-egress-using-ids-ips-leveraging-transit-gateway/. Also take a look at third-party IDS options from AWS partners to understand their architecture (https://aws.amazon.com/mp/scenarios/security/ids/ and https://d1.awsstatic.com/Marketplace/scenarios/security/SEC_01_TSB_Final.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already create an ec2 instance with snort.. An for the first step I want to steer the traffic first from the Snort and after to a server.

Comment: FYI, your architecture is representative of pre-cloud thinking. In an Amazon VPC, Security Groups can perform most functions of a firewall. For an Intrusion Detection System, you could consider AWS WAF (assuming it is for web traffic). There is probably better cloud-friendly ways to achieve your goals. However, yes, you could configure a VPC in this fashion. Just be careful that #1 and #2 do not become bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes I know, I just want to test something! Thank you for you answer

Comment: I also found this 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-ingress-routing-simplifying-integration-of-third-party-appliances/
That maybe help me